# Issue using slider in Android activity

Tags: android

I used this tutorial: http://androidopentutorials.com/android-image-slideshow-using-viewpager/ but I have a problem when I use the slide in a second activity.
I think the problem is in this line:

```
android:name="com.androidopentutorials.imageslideshow.AppData"
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more specific. What is the problem? Is your app crashing, or is it not behaving as expected?

If you want help you'll need to post as much detail as possible, include any errors you encounter and the relevant java and xml files.